# native function naming convention in Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt, dalvik

In a project, I cannot find the names of native functions in the .so libraries.
That is, a native function must be called something like `Java_com_package_ClassName_functionName()`. I do find *functionName* in the .so libraries, but either without the `Java_com_package_ClassName_` prefix, or wrapped into a mangled C++ name.

So:

1. Does Qt (Necessitas) use a special naming convention?
2. If yes, how it is done?
3. If no, what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The naming conventions for JNI functions are given by the Dalvik VM, a library couldn't change them and expect them to work, i.e. be callable from the Java part of the application. But, the Java_package_function convention is only needed for functions that Java wants to call, it it not neccesary for a `C/C++` function calling another one.

If you compile

```
jint Java_com_example_foo(JNIEnv*  env, jobject  this) { return bar(); }
int bar() { return 3; }
```

into a library, you can call `Java_com_example_foo` from java, and you won't be able to call `bar` from java, but nothing prevents `Java_com_example_foo` from calling `bar`.

So, there are 2 possibilities that come to mind:

1. the Java part is nothing but a stub that calls a `main` function in one library, and all the rest is done in `C` or `C++`. This `main` function probably will be called `Java_package_function`, not `main`, but it's the only function that uses this naming convention.
2. There's another wrapper library which provides the `Java_package_function` JNI API calls to the Java part, and calls the C/C++ functions which it imports from a different library. This library would probably be very small, so you might not have considered it interesting, and missed it in your previous analysis.